# Add a run block in AngularJS 1.3.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**How do I add a `run` block to the AngularJS 1.3.8 code below?**

When I try to load the app in the browser, the FireFox debugger indicates that control flow briefly stops at the first line of the `run` block and the first line of the other `module`/`config`/`controllers` without entering into any of them.  And then the program stops before the app is able to load.  By contrast, when I comment out the `run` block below, the Angular app runs properly.

The code is taken from this example app, with the only change being that the `run` block is being added.

```
angular.module('hello', [/*'ngCookies',*/ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home',
        controllerAs : 'controller'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}).run(function ($rootScope, $cookies) {
    var cookieValue = $cookies.get("myCookie");
    if (cookieValue) {
        $rootScope.myCookieVar = cookieValue;
    }
}).controller('navigation',

function($rootScope, $http, $location, $route) {

    var self = this;

    self.tab = function(route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

    $http.get('user').then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        }
    }, function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    });

    self.credentials = {};

    self.logout = function() {
        $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
        });
    }

}).controller('home', function($http) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get('resource/').then(function(response) {
        self.greeting = response.data;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cookies` didn't have `get()` and `set()` methods until version 1.4.

See docs

Try changing to

```
var cookieValue = $cookies.myCookie;
```

Comment: **Thank you!**  That moves the control flow forward.  However, the debugger then shows that the app crashes when the control flow hits the line `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`.  Since this is such a simple, short code example, do you mind commenting?  I do not feel like I can be sure the `run` block is firing because control flow has not gotten to it yet because it stops at the line shown in this comment.

Comment: The console tab in the FireFox debugger shows `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookies`

Comment: did you include angular-cookies.js?

Comment: What is a quick and easy way to do that to resolve this question?  The angular dependencies are built by this pom.xml: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/pom.xml

Comment: And index.html is:  https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/static/index.html

Comment: Is there a way to just add a link to index.html to some web source of angular-cookies.js for testing purposes to resolve this question?

Comment: In the `index.html` in the above comment, I changed the `<script>` links to the following: `<div ng-view class="container"></div><script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-cookies.js"></script><script src="js/hello.js"></script>`, but am still getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you point to a good **JavaScript** Angular2 example app that uses REST?  I am thinking of rebuilding this simple example in Angular2, but I do not want to resort to TypeScript, and I imagine that posting a question asking for links would be frowned upon here.